# Calling object method during creation c++

Tags: c++, instantiation

So say I have an object, say `A`, like this

```
class A {
  private:
    int x;
  public:
    A(){};
    ~A(){};
    void sayA() {
      std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Now If I have a vector of pointers to `A`

```
std::vector<A *> As;
```

can I push back `new` instances of `A` to the vector while at the same time accessing the `sayA` method at the same time?

Like this

```
As.push_back(new A()->sayA());
```

Just to point out in this case `A` is not an Object I created, It's part of a graphics library

Comment: They aren't called "at the same time". Your last line is equivalent to `auto a = new A(); auto b = a->sayA(); As.push_back(b);`.

Comment: Result of 'new A()->sayA()' is void. You'r vector is parameterized with A*. Since sayA returns void - no you can not. If you change it to 'const A* sayA() {... return this;}' then you can try with const_cast.  But you'd better not doing it.

Comment: Please define "during creation". There is something called constructor, which runs exactly what is inside. But in fact, whatever code you write after calling `new` is placed behind the constructor call, so there is essentially no difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can (ab)use `emplace_back` in C++17:

```
As.emplace_back(new A())->sayA();
```

but really, IMO this is more clear:

```
As.push_back(new A());
As.back()->sayA();
```

Comment: Oh this makes sense since `.back()` returns a reference to the last element in the vector. Thank you!

Comment: @Rakete1111 I guess you meant the opposite

Comment: @SOFe Oh; no, the OP mentioned iterator and edited the comment afterwards. :)

Comment: If it's a reference to the last entry, perhaps you need double deref? `As` is a vec of `A *` not `A`.

Comment: @SOFe You'd need double deref if `back()` returned an iterator (once to go through the iterator, and once to go through `A*`). But since it's a reference to the last object, it's a `A*&` which only requires one deref.

Answer (score 6):

You could let `sayA` return a pointer to the instance. Like this:

```
auto sayA() {
  std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
  return this;
}
```

and then insert the instance as follows.

```
As.push_back((new A())->sayA());
```

But apart from making it work, this is awkward and hard to read. Consider using a vector of smart pointers and insert first, then call methods. If `sayA` is part of object construction, call it from `A`'s constructor.

Comment: I sort of wonder if a factory class (if the function callings get complicated) would be an imaginable approach. Would like to hear your thoughts on that.

Comment: @StackDanny Hm, how are we supposed to judge that from the OP's snippet? If construction gets complicated, a factory class might be worth it, but here, it's not complicated?

Comment: I meant that in a purely hypothetical way. (not to suggest you should expand upon that in your answer) :)

Comment: @StackDanny Ok... say if `sayA` is an implementation detail for construction, it should be called by `A::A`. If it's a public member function that _can_ be called after construction, it should be called separately. In both scenarios I wouldn't go with external functionality for construction.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes, **if** you make sure that `sayA()` will return `this`, since `push_back()` will expect pointer to `A`, not void which is current return type of `sayA()`. And if you return any other pointer to `A`, then you will leak you newly allocated object since there will be no way to delete it.

**BUT**

Why you want to have vector of pointers to `A` and have headache of deleting them later if you can have just `std::vector<A> As;` and then you can call `sayA()` as other answers suggested.